# Python catching system Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a program that exposes different API, some of them require a huge amount of time.
Sometimes it happens that an user insert wrong data in the algorithm and has to abort the execution.

I'm trying to create that system raising a keyboardException and catching from another API, but actually without any result.

Can someone please address me ? Below my test code

```
@ns.route('/abort')
class ProjectItem(Resource):
    def get(self):
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
        return None,200


@ns.route('/test')
class ProjectItem(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            print('start')
            time.sleep(5)
            print('end')
            return None,400
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("interrupted, yay!")
            return None,200
```

I have even tryed this way

```
@ns.route('/abort')
class ProjectItem(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print('abort')
        sys.exit("pls pls pls")
        print('aborting')
        return None,200


@ns.route('/test')
class ProjectItem(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            print('start')
            time.sleep(5)
            print('end')
            return None,400
        except:
            print("interrupted, yay!")
            return None,200
```

but still unable to see that agognated "yay"

Comment: How do you expect an exception in handling `/abort` to cause a separate request to fail?  Wouldn’t that make *any* pair of requests capable of killing each other?

Comment: I'm coming from Node.JS, and here for example I can broadcast an event. Is there something similar? 
Is there in Python anything like "System Exception" that are across the entire program?